# Place divs around a centered div in CSS

Tags: css

I have 3 divs. The 'middle' div needs to be centered in the containing element (a seperate div that is the width of the page, basically) while the other two divs should be on either side of the 'middle' div.

Here is what I've tried so far, but as you can see, if the left and right divs aren't even in width, they push the 'middle' div off center.

```
<div class='cont'>
    <div class='name2'>The Man with Six Fingers</div>
    <div class='vs'>VS.</div>
    <div class='name1'>I. Montoya</div>
</div>

.cont{
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
  text-align:center;
}
.cont >div{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7TLSa/

The solution only needs to work in Webkit since this will be in a mobile app.

Comment: What if the side divs are more than half the size of the container?

Comment: @Gareth Good point, I guess I will have to limit them in width somehow? Would something like max-width:35% work?

Comment: @you786 yea I'd say more on the lines of `width:32%;` to all three columns but I'm not sure exactly how responsive you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adjusted the widths, min-width, and white space to tweak its responsiveness. Is this what you're looking for?

See [***DEMO***](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgzhA/?editors=111)

```
.name1, .name2 {
    width:30%;
    min-width:160px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```